# Adding NSLookup to Ping Script

Tags: powershell

I have this ping script that works well for what I need. I want to add to this but not sure how. I want it to output like a NSLookup. Sometimes I have the host name for the printer and would like it to output the IP if one is found and add that to another column.

First EX:

```
    Get-Content "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New folder\hnames.txt" | ForEach-Object { #Change User to your name and after desktop where you have IPs you want to ping
  if(Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    $status = 'Alive'
  }
  else {
    $status = 'Dead'
  }

$dns = Resolve-DnsName $_ -DnsOnly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

  # output 1 object with two separate properties
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Status = $status
    Target = $_
    IPAddress = $dns.IPAddress -join ', '
  }
} |Export-Csv 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New folder\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation #change this to where you want the export to go, Change Output to what you want to save as
```

Second EX:

```
  Get-Content "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New folder\hnames.txt" | ForEach-Object { #Change User to your name and after desktop where you have IPs you want to ping
  if(Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    $status = 'Alive'
  }
  else {
    $status = 'Dead'
  }

  # output 1 object with two separate properties
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Status = $status
    Target = $_
    IPAddress = $success.Address.IPAddressToString
  }
} |Export-Csv 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New folder\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation #change this to where you want the export to go, Change Output to what you want to save as
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing hostname to IP Address you could use the output from `Test-Connection` already, for example:

```
Get-Content ..... | ForEach-Object {
    $status = 'Dead'
    if($success = Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        $status = 'Alive'
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Status    = $status
        Target    = $_
        IPAddress = $success.Address.IPAddressToString
    }
} | Export-Csv ..... -NoTypeInformation
```

Another option is to use [`Resolve-DnsName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname):

```
Get-Content ..... | ForEach-Object {
    $status = 'Dead'
    if(Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        $status = 'Alive'
    }

    $dns = Resolve-DnsName $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Status    = $status
        Target    = $_
        IPAddress = $dns.IPAddress -join ', '
    }
} | Export-Csv ..... -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I Changed my original post with 2 ex both of them output a file with a new column IP Address but nothing in the column. I am using a master text file to ping multiple if that makes a difference.

Comment: @EEVolutionX not sure I understand, those examples using the logic from this answer do not work for your desired output?

Comment: the only thing it does is add a IPAddress Column to my output CSV file but no info in that column.

Comment: @EEVolutionX same with using `$success.Address.IPAddressToString` (the example above) ? I have removed `-DnsOnly` from my code, that may have been the problem.